# Connect-PnPOnline forbidden 403 powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am using the PnP modules to connect to a sharepoint site and retrieve its subsites and the lists within them. However when i try to use the below command it throws (403) forbidden error.

```
#Variables for Processing

$siteUrl = "https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/PS1"
$siteAdminUrl = "https://****-admin.sharepoint.com/"

#Setup Credentials to connect
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Setting up Creds"
#$userCredential= Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Password"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Connecting to Sharepoint online services"
Connect-SPOService -Url $siteAdminUrl
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -CurrentCredentials

$subsites = Get-PnPSubWebs
foreach ($subsite in $subsites) {

Write-Host $subsite.Title
$Lists = Get-PnPList
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Subsite name is " $Subsite.Title" in the site"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "There are totally " $Lists.count " lists available on the site"
foreach ($list in $Lists) {
Write-Host $list.Title
}
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the User must be a O365 tenant administrator as well as site collection admin. I have updated your code and it works fine in my case.

```
#Variables for Processing

$siteUrl = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/PS1"
$siteAdminUrl = "https://xxxxxxx-admin.sharepoint.com/"

#Setup Credentials to connect
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Setting up Creds"
$userCredential= Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Password"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Connecting to Sharepoint online services"
Connect-SPOService -Url $siteAdminUrl
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential $userCredential

$subsites = Get-PnPSubWebs
foreach ($subsite in $subsites) {

Write-Host $subsite.Title
$Lists = Get-PnPList
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Subsite name is " $Subsite.Title" in the site"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "There are totally " $Lists.count " lists available on the site"
foreach ($list in $Lists) {
Write-Host $list.Title
}
}
```

My Output Screen: 
[image]